# Unpack WIX Burn bundle

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

Is it possible to somehow unpack a bundle? I need to make sure all packages within a bundle are signed correctly...

TIA

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dark.exe decompiles bundles; use `-x` to extract the bits.

Comment: thanks for the tip. the tool works, and it extracts everything... except the bundle engine. my primary goal was checking if the engine is signed correctly. i managed to do that by executing the bundle and locating cached engine in c:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}\... (in Win7) btw, engine executable is named the same way the bundle is. i found useful info there too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628362/how-does-burn-in-wix-3-6-bundle-msi-files-into-an-exe

Answer (score 4):

Run the installer with the argument `-layout` and it should download or extract (as appropriate) the packages that it contains to the directory the installer is in. You can specify a target directory as a second argument if you wish.

This was tested with a bundle created with version `3.6.2520.0`. It is known to be broken on the current weekly release of `wix36.exe` itself.

Comment: thanks. looks like it extracts everything except the engine though.

Comment: this doesnt work for me, all it does is to copy the bundle.exe itself. My bundle.exe should and does contain another .exe and an .msi. That's what I want to get out (using wix 3.9 to build it)

Answer (score 4):

insignia will extract the engine.

```
insignia -ib Install.exe  -o engine.exe
```

Then I use signtool to sign the engine then you have to put the engine back into the bundle...

```
insignia -ab engine.exe Install.exe -o Install.exe
```

I then sign the whole bundle