# Can we extract the msi file from burn setup?

Tags: bootstrapper, merge-module

Kindly please help me to know is it possible to extract the msi file from burn exe(exe developed using burn bootstrapper concept)?

Also, i want to know is it possible to pass an burn exe as Merge Module for installation package?

Comment: Added a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Wix provides dark.exe, which can be used for this purpose (using -x).
See [Unpack WIX Burn bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889383/unpack-wix-burn-bundle/8889830#8889830)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Yes: **`dark.exe -x outputfolder MySetup.msi`** will do the trick. [See here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130) (section 4). The merge module part of the question I don't fully follow.