# how to deploy only excel and word through domain server 2012r2

Tags: active-directory, windows-installer, gpo

On my `domain server 2012r2`I am trying to deploying office 2007 but not all of the office I need to install only `excel` and `word`

I found an `.msi` file within the dvd installation and found many `.msi` packages
called `ExcelMUI.msi`and `WordMUI.msi` at directory

> ...\English\Excel.en-us\ExcelMUI.msi
>
> ...\English\Excel.en-us\WordMUI.msi

can I use them to deploy only excel and word through `domain server 2012r2`?
are they valid as `.msi` packages installer ?

Answer (score 0):

***Best Guess***: I wonder if those MUI-setups are [Multilingual User Interface setups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingual_User_Interface). I think you should get on a **virtual machine** and try to run the **`setup.exe`** instead (if there is one) and then go to "**Custom**" or equivalent to see if you get a **feature selection dialog**. Then you should select **Word** and **Excel** to install fully and you can disable most other features (don't disable the shared features, just the other apps would be my suggestion - Outlook, PowerPoint, etc...). It is possible that those MSI files you mention can be used directly. You could try to run them - but only on a virtual of course. Or on a computer which does not matter - test computer of some sort. Look for a custom option and a feature dialog there too. Sorry, all I can suggest without installation media access.

***Sure?***: With all that said, Office on a domain server? Do you mean domain controller? (hope not). Sounds like a very dangerous move if you ask me - with all the security holes Office contains. At least make sure to run Windows Update or Office Update or whatever mechanism you have to deploy security fixes. ***Can I be curious and ask why the server needs Office? Is it for automation only?***

***Viewer for MSI Files***: You can open and inspect MSI files using the free tools [**Orca, SuperOrca or InstEd**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) (links towards bottom). [I have an old answer on superuser showing how MSI features can be seen inside the MSI file](https://superuser.com/a/785825/11906).

Comment: Office on a domain server? `yes I need to install it from domain server but it is not installed at the domain server`  Do you mean domain controller? `umm yes` Can I be curious and ask why the server needs Office? Is it for automation only? `No server does not need office and as you said my friend it is only for automation purpose when I connect a client pc with new fresh OS copy to my domain server I want to make thinks easer as much as I can so office and some other software will be installed by domain server  `

Comment: I will give it try for suggestion but I am not really convinced with size of the `ExcelMUI.msi` itt only about 6 MB hope if someone can provide me with tested `.msi` package

Comment: I have full installation media but as you know my friend I can not install `.exe` files using the domain server I need `.msi` packages to install office or some of it is feature through domain so I am looking for `.msi` package to install office and I prefer to install only excel and word and share feature only we do not use other office feature like outlook, power point or other