# System.IO.FileInfo adds unexpected string to path when used in WIX Custom Action

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I've got an [WIX(V3.11.1)](http://wixtoolset.org/) installer in which I'm creating an [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) based on value which is passed to Custom Action.
Value which was passed to Custom Action is correct, `session.CustomActionData["INSTALLFOLDER"]` returns proper path, which is `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApplication`.

Unfortunately, when I create `FileInfo targetDir = new FileInfo(session.CustomActionData["INSTALLFOLDER"])`, the result of `targetDir.FullName` is `C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE335.tmp-\C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApplication\`.

I've tried to find any information about how constructor of [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) works, but without any result. 
Do you have any ideas why `C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE335.tmp-\` appears in FileInfo and how to create it with real path?

Code which is used by me to check all values:

```
string path = session.CustomActionData["INSTALLFOLDER"];

session.Log(path); //result is C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApplication
FileInfo targetDir = new FileInfo(path);

session.Log(targetDir.FullName); // result is C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE335.tmp-\C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApplication\
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing extra is happening, such as `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApplication` being wrapped in an extra set of quotation marks somewhere in it's journey?

Comment: I'm sure. I added an sample code to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My setup-sense is guessing that the value of `INSTALLFOLDER` in your `CustomActionData` is actually the value `[INSTALLFOLDER]`. When logging, that syntax will get resolved to its proper value. That is why it looks good. However, what `FileInfo` is actually getting is a value like:

```
FileInfo targetDir = new FileInfo("[INSTALLFOLDER]");
```

Which of course is "The file named "[INSTALLFOLDER]" in the current directory". That matches your second log line.

The fix would be to ensure you're passing the **value of** `INSTALLFOLDER` in your CustomActionData. A few different ways to do that depending how you are scheduling your deferred custom action and setting the named property. For example, using `SetProperty` should be an easy way to fix it.

Update: Hawex provided a snippet that defined the custom action. It looked like:

```
<Property Id="CustomActionOnInstall" Value="INSTALLFOLDER=[INSTALLFOLDER]" />

<CustomAction Id="CustomActionOnInstall" BinaryKey="CustomActions" Execute="deferred" 
              Impersonate="no"  DllEntry="OnInstall" Return="check" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CustomActionOnInstall" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>      
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

to fix, just change the static (unevaluated) `Property` to a `SetProperty` like so:

```
<SetProperty Id="CustomActionOnInstall" Value="INSTALLFOLDER=[INSTALLFOLDER]"
             Before="CustomActionOnInstall" Sequence="execute" />
```

Comment: I'd drop in a temporary MessageBox.Show() or attach a debugger to the CA to see what's really going on.

Comment: Throwing in a link to [MSI custom action debugging info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880033/129130).

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I've edited your answer and placed a code used by me to solve this issue.