# Folder not getting created by custom action of Wix Installer

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

Folder not getting created in Local Disk C using Custom Action of a Wix Installer.

```
namespace MyCustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult MySimpleAction(Session session)
        {
            string country = session["COUNTRIES"];

            string root = @"C:\Temp";

            try
            {

                if (!Directory.Exists(root))
                {
                   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\country.txt", country);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the installer log show?  Is your custom action executed?  Does it have any exceptions logged?

Comment: Just in case you want [some information on how to hook up the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880033/129130). Check the video from Advanced Installer. But more than that, what are you doing there with that country.txt file? There might be better ways to do it.

Comment: The installer shows no error. I am saving the item selected from the combo box list (that appears in the dialogue of the wix installer) in the country.txt file. But I am not able to create the temp folder from the above code and for now I am creating it manually. Is there a way to create a folder using a Custom Action.Moreover, is there also a way to make my combo box selection compulsory in wix installer dialogue? @SteinÅsmul,@Christopher Painter

Comment: I have to use Wix installer only.

Comment: The video from Advanced Installer is a general purpose video of how to debug custom actions, it has validity even if you use WiX. Could you write the selection from that combo box to the registry instead?

Comment: I didn't ask what the installer said. I  asked what the installer log shows.  You don't show the WiX code that defines and sequences the custom action that calls this code so I don't have any way of know that this custom action is even being called.

Comment: Thanks for the responses my Custom Action is working now.