# WiX escape XPath brackets in CustomActionData

Tags: c#, .net, wix, escaping, installation

I want to call Custom action, which is a deferred C# method, with key/value pair that contains XPath and therefore brackets.

I define action as
`<CustomAction Id= 'action1.smth' Property='action1' Value="TARGETXPATH=/configuration/application[\[]@name='xService'[\]]/@address/>`

Logging verbose installation I can see custom action is called as 
`Executing op: CustomActionSchedule ... TARGETXPATH=/configuration/application[@name='xService']/@address`

Great, but when same value is session.log-ed I get

`'/configuration/application/@address'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out when I debugged the custom action. Turns out `session.Log()` escapes the brackets again so the wrong value is put in the verbose log, but other than that correct values were propagated to the custom action.

Comment: [Debugging MSI Custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878332/wixsharp-debug-custom-action-in-console/52880033#52880033).