# Custom Action Wix doesn't Run on Visual Studio Build

Tags: visual-studio, wix

We are building our installer using an automated run via TFS (Visual Studio Build)

Builds find and I have downloaded it, However when I run the installer,

See this image:

[image: Prematrure ended]

I found out (by isolation) that the cause of error is the Custom Actions I made.
Somehow, my custom action causes an error, but i don't know what error is that.

of course when I run it in dev environment it works.

Can someone shed a light with the issue?

Comment: Maybe you miss permision. Add logs to custom action session.Log. File with log you find in ..\ AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: [Here is an answer on how to debug custom actions using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880033/129130). You can usually also get a rough idea of what is wrong by [enabling verbose logging with extra debugging information as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130). `msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log`

Comment: Thank you for the answers, found out that the issue is on my logic on creating a txt file.

Comment: Create your text file on application launch. Familiar territory, single source and keeps your setup simpler and more robust.