# Have to prompt UAC in windows 7 for msi

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project

I am trying to create an Installation package (MSI) using the Microsoft setup project which requires admin privileges.

On Windows 7, the UAC prompt does not show up. Message window says need admin permissions.

How to make Windows 7 prompt UAC for a non-privileged user?

When a non-privileged user on windows 10 tries to install the MSI, it automatically prompts the UAC window.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your Win 7 system is actually set to display the UAC in the settings?

Comment: should I check that in User Account Control settings?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975787/guided-help-adjust-user-account-control-settings-in-windows-7-and-wind

Comment: It works if I set "Always Notify" in Windows 7, but on Windows 10 UAC prompts even if UAC is set to "Never Notify".

Comment: Are there any entries in the **`LaunchConditions`** table? They will be spoofed on Windows 10, but probably not on Windows 7 - not sure. Check the compiled MSI - the one you actually install - [using the Orca tool or equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48482545/129130). What is in the table? )if anything).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Package` element's `InstallPrivileges` attribute to `elevated`. Or better, if you're creating a per-machine package, set the `Package` element's `InstallScope` attribute to `perMachine` and it will do the right thing for you.

```
<Product ...>
  <Package InstallScope='perMachine' />
```

Comment: All the above settings (WIX) work for Windows 10, but I am not able to get it to work for win 7. FYI I am using Visual Studio Installer.