# Changing the ALLUSERS property with Electron-Wix-Msi

Tags: electron, wix

I want to change the ALLUSERS property in Wix from 2 to 1. In my wxs file:

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes" Value="2" />
```

In Electron-wix-msi, my file set the UI property:

```
ui: {
        chooseDirectory: true,
        template: '<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes" Value="1" />'
    },
```

I get an error though because it is a duplicate property. Is there no way to change the value with electron-wix-msi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Disclaimer***: I don't do Electron installers. I can show you how it can be done using regular WiX markup. Please try the below and see how it works for you ([resources for learning WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)):

---

You can remove the hardcoded property from your source and rely on WiX's built in handling of this in the **Package element** - the attribute: **`InstallScope="perMachine"`**. Setting this attribute to perMachine will create the ALLUSERS property for you in the MSI with a value of 1.

***Quick Sample***:

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Test" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0" 
           Manufacturer="N/A" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

 <..>

</Wix>
```

Along with other attributes - such as **`InstallPrivileges`** - setting **`InstallScope`** to **`perMachine`** will create a per-machine installer [as described by Rob Mensching here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027979/129130). Make your changes and observe the resulting changes in the output MSI by inspecting it with Orca in the usual fashion.

I just remembered that I have this old github sample for per user WiX installations: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXPerUserSample

---

***Links:***

- [On the topic of per-user MSI installations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266302/129130) (how-to, difficulties and peculiarities)

Comment: This answer, in addition to this pull request changes, fixed my problem: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-wix-msi/pull/138