# .NET framework 4.0 install fails

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

I am having issues installing a program by Cornelsen.

The setup dialog prompts that NET framework 4.0 is needed in order to install.

[image]

I have installed NET framework 4.8 and I have not found a way to downgrade.

Any idea on how to fix the prompt?

**EDIT:** @Filburt I have tried following your link and get this prompt

[image]

**FIX:** Thanks to @Stein Åsmul using SuperOrca and simply changing the RegLocator Value from .../1031 to .../1033 enabled the MSI to run.

[image]

Comment: The error message it instructs you to install the [German Language Package](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=3324) in addition to the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: @Filburt It will not let me install this either. The prompt says .NET Framework 4 ist already part of the OS.

Comment: That installer was authored mistakenly so it cannot detect properly that you have 4.8 installed. Except asking its vendor for a patched installer, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Lex Li. I will write them an e-mail.

Comment: Do contact the vendor, that is always necessary when you see outright errors and problems with an installer, but I have added some hints below for how you could potentially work around the problems you see. Maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***LaunchCondition***: This looks like a regular MSI LaunchCondition. These are logical conditions that must be met (be true) for the installation to be allowed to proceed. You should be able to disable the condition by opening the MSI and removing the launch condition in question from the [LaunchCondition table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/launchcondition-table). You need an [MSI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130) to do so. Orca is Microsoft's own tool, it is installed with Visual Studio and the Windows SDK. Try searching for **`Orca-x86_en-us.msi`** - under **`Program Files (x86)`** and install the MSI you find, or maybe try [SuperOrca](http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html).

***Modifying MSI***: You are supposed to create an MST (transform) to change an MSI file (essentially a database change fragment to apply to the original MSI database file at runtime), but you can "hotfix" an existing MSI if you are in a hurry. Make a zip or copy of the original MSI first. Then just delete offending entries from the [LaunchCondition table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/launchcondition-table). I suppose you can add **`"OR 1"`** to the existing condition as well - I think that should work to make the condition always true.

***Error Condition***: Removing a launch condition will allow you to install the MSI whilst the condition in question is not true, but it will not fix the actual error condition that your MSI is warning you about - you just suppress the error. In your case, you could try to install the German language pack for .NET 4.8 yourself first (that might even satisfy the current launch condition - I do not know): https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48