# Setup requires.Net Famework Verison 3.5. Visual Studio Installer project, Even though 3.5 is enabled in windows feature

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I'm trying to install from an installer project on visual studio 2015 targeting the .Net 3.5 Framework. When I run the project I get this error
[image]
I Have 3.5 and 4.8 installed currently and have turned on the framework in the windows features
[image]
 When a friend builds an installer for me based on the same project, I can install just fine. I'm not sure what is really going on here. I've copy his project, repaired my visual studio, delete some files for SDK/Bootstrapper/package, reinstalled 3.5 but nothing has worked. I wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

EDIT.
Launch conditions orca 
[image]
Launch condition visual studio 
[image]

Comment: Using [Orca or an equivalent tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130), open your MSI. Please report the content of the [LaunchCondition table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/launchcondition-table). On systems with Visual Studio installed look for the Orca installer - `Orca-x86_en-us.msi` -  under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86` (numbers will vary after the "bin" folder).

Comment: Here is a little answer on how to stop conditions from unexpectedly preventing uninstalls: [to the Batmobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55183152/129130). LaunchConditions must be true or else the setup is aborted.

Comment: Hi Stein Asmul, my launch conditions are blank, see my edit, although my launch conditions in visual studio are different, see edit

Comment: Oh, yes. These are probably custom actions. I think I remember seeing this before. There should be an answer on it. Look in the CustomAction table and see what is there.

Comment: [Maybe check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233333/visual-studio-2019-installer-project-how-to-remove-launch-condition-for-net-fr). I am just heading out the door for a while. Didn't have time to review it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying, I ended up repairing the installer extension and that seemed to work. I'm not sure how I got into the mess or why it work but it did.

Comment: Great that it worked. [A few words of warning on Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). Great when they work, but usually don't scale well. Just a heads-up. WiX is fully functional, but complicated ([quick start links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130)). [List of MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840). Some free features in Advanced Installer and a lot of IIS functionality (beyond what I have had time to test).

Comment: Not sure if Installshield has any free versions with limited functionality as of now (they had some before). Lots of features and very good documentation. IIS functionality was limited back in the day.

Comment: Yes, working on getting ready to head out the door! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the help and all the awesome responses Stein Asmul . We have switched over to install shield on a few of our newer projects but I was tasked with updating some legacy code. I'll be working on switch this as well to install shield