# The installer was interrupted before XXX could be installed. You need to restart the installer and try again (windows application install)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have a Windows application developed in VS2019 using .NET Framework 4.7.2
I have built the MSI and installed in on many test computers. All have worked fine.

Now, we are installing onto a clients computers and getting the following:

[image]

I have looked at the log and here it is: (I cut what I could to make the char count fit)

```
=== Verbose logging started: 1/8/21  2:01:40  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (10:2C) [02:01:40:090]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (10:2C) [02:01:40:090]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:150]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:150]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:150]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:151]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:174]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:178]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:178]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:180]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:185]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:185]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:188]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:188]: Original package ==> C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:188]: Package we're running from ==> C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:190]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:190]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{99CA1A75-1EFC-4530-8C27-143371369A13}'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:190]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:200]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:205]: Enabling baseline caching for this transaction since all active patches are MSI 3.0 style MSPs or at least one MSI 3.0 minor update patch is active
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{99CA1A75-1EFC-4530-8C27-143371369A13}'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\test.log'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=16144 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{7CCE4337-DB30-4C18-A462-C0D5AF2782B2}'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{99CA1A75-1EFC-4530-8C27-143371369A13}'
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{99CA1A75-1EFC-4530-8C27-143371369A13}'
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:206]: Package name extracted from package path: 'QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi'
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: Package to be registered: 'QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi'
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: Running product '{99CA1A75-1EFC-4530-8C27-143371369A13}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '16144'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:207]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiSystemRebootPending property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:208]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:208]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:208]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming
```

*** removed crap here to reduce amount of characters ***

```
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:217]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'Reception1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:228]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:229]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:229]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:229]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\'.
MSI (c) (10:2C) [02:01:40:230]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '5.00'.
=== Logging started: 1/8/21  2:01:40 ===
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:248]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:248]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:248]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:248]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:248]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Font 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:252]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:252]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:252]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:256]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:256]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:256]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Action 2:01:40: INSTALL. 
Action start 2:01:40: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:258]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:258]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:258]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:258]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
Action 2:01:40: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Action start 2:01:40: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:258]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:260]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 14912
MSI (c) (10:1C) [02:01:40:260]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\RECEPT~1.INL\AppData\Local\Temp\MSICEFE.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (10:88) [02:01:40:261]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (10:88) [02:01:40:262]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (10:88) [02:01:40:262]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:357]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 14888
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:357] [CheckFX                                 ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:357] [CheckFX                                 ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:363] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDFrameworkVersion'
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:364] [CheckFX                                 ]: Allocating space...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:364] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDFrameworkVersion'...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:364] [CheckFX                                 ]: Property 'VSDFrameworkVersion'  retrieved with value 'v4.7.2'.
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:365] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDFrameworkProfile'
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:365] [CheckFX                                 ]: Property 'VSDFrameworkProfile'  retrieved with value ''.
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:365] [CheckFX                                 ]: Set VSDNETMSG with the FrameworkVersion.
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:365] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDNETMSG'
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:366] [CheckFX                                 ]: Allocating space...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:366] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDNETMSG'...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:366] [CheckFX                                 ]: Property 'VSDNETMSG'  retrieved with value 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:366]: Creating MSIHANDLE (3) of type 790531 for thread 14888
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:367] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:367] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'VSDNETMSG' to 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version v4.7.2.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:367]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VSDNETMSG property. Its current value is 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'. Its new value: 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version v4.7.2.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:367]: Closing MSIHANDLE (3) of type 790531 for thread 14888
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:367] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDNETURLMSG'
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:367] [CheckFX                                 ]: Allocating space...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:368] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDNETURLMSG'...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:368] [CheckFX                                 ]: Property 'VSDNETURLMSG'  retrieved with value 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:368]: Creating MSIHANDLE (4) of type 790531 for thread 14888
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:368] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:369] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'VSDNETURLMSG' to 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version v4.7.2.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:369]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VSDNETURLMSG property. Its current value is 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?'. Its new value: 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version v4.7.2.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:369]: Closing MSIHANDLE (4) of type 790531 for thread 14888
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:369] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:369] [CheckFX                                 ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'VSDFXAvailable' to 'TRUE'.
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:370]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VSDFXAvailable property. Its value is 'TRUE'.
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:370] [CheckFX                                 ]: Writing config file with version: '4.0'...

INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:374] [CheckFX                                 ]: Custom Action succeeded.
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:375] [CheckFX                                 ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '0'
MSI (c) (10!28) [02:01:40:376]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 14888
MSI (c) (10:1C) [02:01:40:378]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 14912
Action ended 2:01:40: DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:379]: Skipping action: ERRCA_UIANDADVERTISED (condition is false)
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:379]: Doing action: AppSearch
Action 2:01:40: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 2:01:40: AppSearch.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:379]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
Action ended 2:01:40: AppSearch. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:380]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 2:01:40: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 2:01:40: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 2:01:40: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:380]: Doing action: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions
Action 2:01:40: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions. 
Action start 2:01:40: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:380]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions' 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:381]: Creating MSIHANDLE (8) of type 790542 for thread 14912
MSI (c) (10:A0) [02:01:40:382]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\RECEPT~1.INL\AppData\Local\Temp\MSICF7C.tmp, Entrypoint: VsdLaunchConditions
MSI (c) (10!F0) [02:01:40:396]: Creating MSIHANDLE (9) of type 790531 for thread 13808
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:396] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:396] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:397] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Enumerating table using SQL statement: 'SELECT * FROM `_VsdLaunchCondition`'
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:397] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Calling MsiGetActiveDatabase...
MSI (c) (10!F0) [02:01:40:397]: Creating MSIHANDLE (10) of type 790541 for thread 13808
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:398] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiDatabaseOpenViewW - Prepare Database to view table...
MSI (c) (10!F0) [02:01:40:398]: Creating MSIHANDLE (11) of type 790540 for thread 13808
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:398] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: TMsiViewExecute - Open Database view on table...
MSI (c) (10!F0) [02:01:40:398]: Creating MSIHANDLE (12) of type 790531 for thread 13808
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:398] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:398] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:398] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:399] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:399] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Evaluating condition 'VSDFXAvailable'...
INFO   : [01/08/2021 02:01:40:399] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: RESULT:  Condition is true. Nothing more to do.

MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying TARGETDIR property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding _D584FE7D7AF24DC18095011B0B18A5C6 property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QuickTech.Com\'.
  

MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding _06ECEE199A9F415B9855B89A6E942917 property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\QuickTech.Com\'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding _33268EE4668A481EB3BED40A8F0F5C6C property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Target path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Note: target paths subject to change (via custom actions or browsing)
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Dir (target): Key: TARGETDIR    , Object: C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Dir (target): Key: ProgramMenuFolder    , Object: C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Dir (target): Key: _D584FE7D7AF24DC18095011B0B18A5C6    , Object: C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QuickTech.Com\
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Dir (target): Key: _3B8F5BB0F8F241EB864527ADC4546637    , Object: C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:411]: Dir (target): Key: StartupFolder    , Object: C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\

MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:485]: Doing action: ExecuteAction
Action 2:01:40: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 2:01:40: ExecuteAction.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:486]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:487]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:487]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:488]: Switching to server: TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\" _06ECEE199A9F415B9855B89A6E942917="C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\QuickTech.Com\" _33268EE4668A481EB3BED40A8F0F5C6C="C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\" NEWPROPERTY1="C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\ProgramData\" _332C30AAA7404C57815468553491214B="C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\ProgramData\QuickTech.Com\" _EA96B1481F294DB38C3FC26FC670C80F="C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\ProgramData\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\" _17CF3A659D2943D280038FDCADF7881F="C:\Program Files\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\ProgramData\QuickTech.Com\QuickTech Offline Agent\History\" _D584FE7D7AF24DC18095011B0B18A5C6="C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QuickTech.Com\" _3B8F5BB0F8F241EB864527ADC4546637="C:\Users\Reception1.INLINEORTHO\A
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:496]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\AIS Offline Agent Inline Ortho\QuickTechOfflineAgentSetup.msi
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:496]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (D4:A4) [02:01:40:498]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:501]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:501]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:501]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:501]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:506]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (D4:78) [02:01:40:508]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:509]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:509]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:509]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 2:01:40: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:509]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 2:01:40: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 2:01:40: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:40:510]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
Action 2:01:40: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:547]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: _RemoveFilePath 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:547]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DuplicateFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:547]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ReserveCost 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:551]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CostingComplete property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PublishComponent 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SelfReg 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Font 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (10:B4) [02:01:40:552]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
Action ended 2:01:42: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
Action ended 2:01:42: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:035]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (10:88) [02:01:42:036]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.

Property(C): VSDNETCOREDESKTOPRTNAME = .NET Core Desktop Runtime
Property(C): VSDNETCORERTNAME = .NET Core Runtime
Property(C): VSDNETCOREMSG = This setup requires the [2] [3] version [1].  Please install the [3] and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDNETCOREURLMSG = This setup requires the [2] [3] version [1].  Please install the [3] and run this setup again.  The [3] can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version v4.7.2.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(C): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher.  Please install Internet Information Server and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version v4.7.2.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.
Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed.

=== Logging stopped: 1/8/21  2:01:42 ===
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:061]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:061]: Product: QuickTech Offline Agent -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:064]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: QuickTech Offline Agent. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: QuickTech.Com. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:066]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:066]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (10:40) [02:01:42:068]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 1/8/21  2:01:42 ===
```

I am not sure what the error is referring to.
.NET Framework 4.7.2 is not installed but is set to a pre-launch condidtion and .Net 4.8 is installed.
The user I am installing under has admin rights (I can create folders and such as the user)

I have checked the other answers and the folders are not encrypted,
System account has full access,
The app is not installed on the computer already.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can't debug this right now. Skimming it I am thinking [you should have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243191/129130). I don't remember all the details, but this looks similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets just close this one. Somehow, I rebuilt the MSI files with some other bug fixes and it is now working. I am not sure what to put here as there is no real fix.

Comment: You can just set your own answer accepted.

Answer (score -1):

This was a microsoft UPDATE rerouting, denoting and limiting your powers and access within your own system, location of line by line output found

here:C:\Users\your username\AppData\Local\Temp - simply use Notepad ++ and go line by line, anyone with any knowledge of systems, access control and 3rd party rights would be outraged to discover how microsoft executes overrides on users authorities, removes 3rd party file structures and replaces them with ones called from their databases, not your 3rd party apps provided by your trusted sources, follow the calls, the references and you will see, beware anyone relying on NordVPN, or anything thats been successfully preserving any one persons privacy, MS dissolved my original install of NORD, restructured the entire path, HKEY values and more, much much more, they also added a return reference to THEIR version of the NORD.exe, with reference to script to denote and redirect installs of the original exe or any matching key values.

ALSO - They added dozens of ways to do as they wish, import, export and send triggered data captures based on your actions and use of anything they please, i know this based on logs,
Zone Alarm is the BEST application controller for windows, and i make sure its god, numerous installs via MS updates they targeted Zone Alarm, virtually containerized it and removed and rerouted its permissions and ability to be anything more then  admin...

This is no joke, its serious