# What's the process of msf5's creating a msi file?

Tags: windows-installer

I know msf5 use a .msi template for injecting, there's PAYLOAD tag in the binary data of the file, while generating the msi file, it firstly inject an exe file to the tag position. What I wanna know is the format of the .msi file and what's the template of exe for generating msi.

I've read the code of msf, the generating logic is in the exe.rb, but I am just confused about the process of generating a msi file, any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I've read this : http://rewtdance.blogspot.com/2013/03/metasploit-msi-payload-generation.html

Comment: http://rewtdance.blogspot.com/2013/03/metasploit-msi-payload-generation.html I found this ,maybe helpful.

Comment: Not related to msf5, but [here is some information on the MSI format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130).