# How to repack Wix Burn bundle?

Tags: wix, bundle, pack, burn, wix3.8

I used method to unpack bundle with dark.exe -x mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889383/unpack-wix-burn-bundle)

how to repack bundle's content back to exe? in simpliest way...
(there are dll's, manifest.xml and other bundle specific content)

TIA

Comment: Does the [WiX toolset diagram](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/tools.html) help?

Comment: The diagram doesn't help because it doesn't have a path from EXE to dark.exe and back again.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by myself:

1. Extract bundle with dark.exe -x
2. Modify any file needed
3. Extract bundle with PowerArchiver (files are extracted as 0, u1, u2, u3, etc.)
4. Replace modified file in folder that PowerArchiver created
   (u need to find appropriate file with file size and rename it to uXX, where XX is numbers)
5. Create cab archive MSzip with PowerArchiver
6. Open bundle with HxD binary editor and find 4D534346 or MSCF which stands for cab archive begin bytes and select it to the end of archive and remove this section
7. Open cab Archive that created with PowerArchiver in HxD and select all and copy, then paste it to bundle and save
8. So you created a modified bundle.exe

Comment: This procedure is a bit exotic, what did you need to replace and how did you deploy the final EXE? You can generally use the extracted MSI files from within the setup.exe to adapt using standardized techniques (transforms and command lines) and this is a field in and of itself *"deployment, distribution & repackaging of applications"*. If you are in a big company there will generally be a whole team dedicated to this sort of task. [Previous answer on repackaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289402/silent-run-installer-exe-with-parameters-on-windows/53296461#53296461).

Comment: Yes it is, but because there is no automated procedure of it and no software for this type of task. Also wix bundle is not similar to msi installers. And when i needed to modify wix bundle exe there was no such info at any resources.

Comment: A WiX bundle generally contains `MSI`, `setup.exe`, or other executables *"run in sequence"* with more options such as `downloading runtimes` and such things. It can be de-compressed like you did and then you may even be able to [de-compress / extract the embedded setup.exe files in various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130) - [and also extract MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130). Finally: [Some information about the MSI format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546).