# Wix installation in silent mode failed

Tags: cmd, wix, installation, verbose

I am trying to install wix.exe through cmd in silent mode , but getting following error in log. Please help to find the reason.
command used : msiexec /i wix.exe /qn /l*v MyLogFile.txt

```
=== Verbose logging started: 2/28/2019  22:10:43  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:033]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:033]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:033]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: wix.exe
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:036]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:036]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:537]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:537]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:545]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:589]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction F:\softwares\wix.exe
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:593]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (28:7C) [22:10:43:601]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (28:7C) [22:10:43:601]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (28:7C) [22:10:43:601]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: F:\softwares\wix.exe
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (28:7C) [22:10:43:605]: Note: 1: 2203 2: F:\softwares\wix.exe 3: -2147286960 
MSI (s) (28:7C) [22:10:43:605]: MainEngineThread is returning 1620
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:684]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:684]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:684]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:684]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:688]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (28:48) [22:10:43:688]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:692]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (84:98) [22:10:43:692]: MainEngineThread is returning 1620
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2/28/2019  22:10:43 ===
```

Comment: You can't install an EXE file with Windows Installer? It consumes only MSI files and a few other types (MSP and MST, etc...). What file is this? Something you downloaded?

Comment: Okay.. thanks for your reply.. can you please help me with how to do silent installation for .exe in windows?

Comment: Where did you download this file? Is it the Wix html framework?

Answer (score 1):

***Setup.exe, "Anything"***: Too long for a comment. A **`setup.exe`** can be "anything" - made using many different tools and feature many different technologies - and there is no general rule for how to install them silently.

***Existing Answers***: I can provide some links as a start, until we know more about what this file really is:

- [How to run an installation in /silent mode with adjusted settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327442/how-to-run-an-installation-in-silent-mode-with-adjusted-settings/52338626#52338626)
- [Silent run installer (.exe) with parameters on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289402/silent-run-installer-exe-with-parameters-on-windows/53296461#53296461)
- [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)

Please skim these links, I guess the first one might be the most accessible? Not sure.